# RDD accessing values in another RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an `RDD` that needs to access data from another `RDD`. However, I always get a `Task not Serializable` error. I have extended the `Serializable` Class however it has not worked. The code is:

```
val oldError = rddOfRatings.aggregate(0.0)((accum, rating) =>
accum + calcError(rating.rating,
us.lookup(rating.user)(0),
it.lookup(rating.product)(0)).abs, _+_ ) / rddSize
```

Where `us`, `it` and `rddOfRatings` are the other `RDD`'s. What I don't understand is, that if an `RDD` is immutable, then why won't it let me allow access to an `RDD` from within another `RDD`? The problem seems to lie with `us` and `it` as when I remove them for a local collection it works fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rdd.lookup`[1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html) is an expensive operation that you probably don't want to do even if you could.

Also, "serializing" an RDD does not make sense, as an RDD is just a reference to data and not data in itself.

The approach to take here will probably depend on the size of those datasets. If `us` and `it` RDDs are about the same size as `rddOfRatings` (which is what it looks like, given the intended lookups),   the best way would be to join those beforehand.

// please note I'm not aware of the actual structure of your collections, so take this as an illustrative example

```
val ratingErrorByUser = us.map(u => (u.id, u.error))
val ratingErrorByProduct = it.map(i=> (i.id, i.error)) 
val ratingsBykey = rddOfRatings.map(r=> (r.user, (r.product, r.rating)))
val ratingsWithUserError = ratingsByKey.join(ratingErrorByUser)
val ratingsWithProductError = ratingsWithUserError.map{case (userId, ((prodId, rating),userErr))} => (prodId,(rating, userErr))}
val allErrors = ratingsWithProductError.join(ratingErrorByProduct)
val totalErr = allErrors.map{case (prodId,((rating, userErr),prodErr)) => calcError(userErr, math.abs(prodErr), rating)}.reduce(_+_)
val total = totalErr / rddOfRatings.count
```

This is probably a lot easier with [Spark DataFrame API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html)

[1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html) if lookup is a must (doesn't look like in this case!), have a look at Spark [IndexedRdd](http://spark-packages.org/package/amplab/spark-indexedrdd)

Comment: Thank you. It inspired me to alter my code and  to remove `lookup`. IndexedRdd is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

RDD's are indeed unserializable due to the variables they have to capture (SparkContext for example). To get around this problem, join the three RDDs together, and you will have all the necessary values in your accumulator closure.